# Android Gcm onMessage().. Recived "null" on some devices why?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Android Gcm onMessage().. Received "null" on some devices Like "Android 4.4  LG GPad 1.0" and "Android 6.0 Lg G4"..
But in some devices Gcm recives correct message Like "Android 5.1 Samsung J5 and J2"...
What is the issue which i cant get ....
Here is the code...

```
 protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    //Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");



 <receiver
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action droid:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="com.xtravoapps.premierdocfinder" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="MYPACKAGENAME.GCMIntentService" />
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to see my gcm notification in all android mobile devices..... but notification recive some devices... and some devices recives "null"... why

Comment: Post more code snippets. Your full receiver, full manifest, the payload your sending. It would be helpful if we can see those. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

We are getting null message on our push notification to several Android devices version 6.0.1, 5.0.1 and 4.4.4. Without changing the Android app or server app, some devices are getting null while many other devices are getting the correct message but more and more devices are getting null.

As it turns out based on our test, the Android devices (phones, tablet) that are getting null push notification message are devices with Google Play Services version of 9.4.52. Other devices with earlier version of the Google Play services are working ok until they get auto updated to 9.4.52.

We downgraded several devices that are receiving null from 9.4.52 back to earlier versions. After the downgrade, we send push notification to these devices and they are getting the message correctly and fixed the null message issue.

Asking our Android users to downgrade play services for our app notification may not be practical so working to see if there are any changes we can do to alleviate this problem with Play Services 9.4.52.

Hope this helps answer the question "GCM why receiving null on some devices".

Answer (score 0):

it may be because there googlePlay services are not updated